# mysqli returns 1 row instead of 2

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this query:

```
SELECT `ca`.*, `a`.* FROM `container_asset` AS `ca` LEFT JOIN `asset` AS `a` ON ca.asset_id = a.id WHERE `container_id` = '4' AND `deleted` = '0' AND `reason` IN ('main', 'previous_version') ORDER BY `reason` ASC, `asset_id` DESC
```

and I am expecting to returns two rows, but when I execute the query with this command:

```
$conn =new  \mysqli('localhost', 'root', '12345', 'assetdb') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$res3 = $conn->query("SELECT `ca`.*, `a`.* FROM `container_asset` AS `ca` LEFT JOIN `asset` AS `a` ON ca.asset_id = a.id WHERE `container_id` = '4' AND `deleted` = '0' AND `reason` IN ('main', 'previous_version') ORDER BY `reason` ASC, `asset_id` DESC");
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res3))
        {
            echo $r['id']."\n";
        }
```

it returns 1 row while fetching results
But when I execute the query directly (in heidisql or phpmyadmin) it returns the expected results, 2 rows.

I cannot explaing this problem?

**EDIT**

I make some more test, if I am expecting 5 rows it returns 4, so it returns 1 row less.

**EDIT2**

data:
container_asset table, asset_id foreing key in asset->id:

```
"container_id"  "asset_id"  "reason"
"1"          "2"    "main"
"2"          "1"    "main"
"3"          "3"    "main"
"4"          "3"    "previous_version"
"4"          "4"    "main"
```

asset table

```
"id"    "asset_class"   "deleted"   "file_name"
"1" "video"          "0"             "ÄÖ.jpg"
"2" "image"          "0"             "èungrandeguitar.jpg"
"3" "image"          "0"              "3.jpg"
"4" "image"          "0"              "çàù.jpg"
```

**EDIT 3**

Even if I remove the join the result is still wrong:

```
SELECT `ca`.* FROM `container_asset` AS `ca` WHERE ca.`container_id` = '4'  AND `reason` IN ('main', 'previous_version') ORDER BY `reason` ASC, `asset_id` DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried with `var_dump()` also?.. **Side note**I thought perhaps it was because you made the jump from object to procedural and perhaps the pointer had been moved twice. But I tested that and it doesn't seem to be the case. Which record is missing? The first, the last, or a random one?

Comment: Yes I have tried the var_dump, always ["num_rows"]=>int(1). The procedural style does not have any effect here, because my original query is made with ZF2 and the same results.

Comment: Can we see the data you're working with?

Comment: added data, sorry for formation, but I am no good stackoverflow tags

Comment: SORRY GUYS, I am dump in my head, I was using another DB on php and ANOTHER (old copy) one in phpmyadmin... X|